# HTML5 audio not streaming same file on multiple computers

Tags: html, html5-audio

I'm using the HTML5 audio tag to create a music player on my remote server. The audio tag works as expected when one computer is playing.

However, I'm getting a problem where if two computers are trying to play the same audio file, one of them will not stream until the other has paused its playing, finished streaming, or stopped streaming.

Is there some programming/server configuration that lets me stream the same file to multiple devices at the same time?

Here's the code, as requested

```
<html>
<body>
    <audio id="jukebox" controls>
    <source id="musiclocation" src="/music/test.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
    </audio>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML code for your player? What do you mean by _my remote server_?

Comment: What server are you running? It sounds like your server is only serving one request at once; for instance, if you are running Apache, and have only one process or thread running. But its hard to tell without details about your server, version, configuration, whether you're running it yourself or on a shared host, etc.